# AssemblyQualifiedName without version and Culture

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a library persisting types like this:

`DocumentManagement.SupplierInvoiceTag, DocumentManagement`

`typeof(SupplierInvoiceTag).AssemblyQualifiedName` returns

```
DocumentManagement.SupplierInvoiceTag, DocumentManagement, Version=0.14.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

Is there a .NET framework method to get the type information in the style of the library without modifying the output from `AssemblyQualifiedName` myself?

Comment: What is "type information in the style of the library ". Are you looking for [Type.FullName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.fullname?view=net-6.0)?

Comment: I tried this first but it does not include the assembly name: `DocumentManagement.SupplierInvoiceTag`. Yes, I could use it together with `Type.Assembly.FullName.Split(',').First()` (pseudo code) but I was curious if this is necessary.

Comment: Have you tried to check how it serializes the type by inspecting the library with *ILSpy*?